# MongoDB aggregation performance capability

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am trying to work through some performance considerations about using MongoDb for a considerable amount of documents to be used in a variety of aggregations.

I have read that a collection has 32TB capcity depending on the sizes of chunk and shard key values.

If I have 65,000 customers who each supply to us (on average) 350 sales transactions per day, that ends up being about 22,750,000 documents getting created daily. When I say a sales transaction, I mean an object which is like an invoice with a header and line items. Each document I have is an average of 2.60kb.

I also have some other data being received by these same customers like account balances and products from a catalogue. I estimate about 1,000 product records active at any one time.

Based upon the above, I approximate 8,392,475,0,00 (8.4 billion) documents in a single year with a total of 20,145,450,000 kb (18.76Tb) of data being stored in a collection.

Based upon the capacity of a MongoDb collection of 32Tb (34,359,738,368 kb) I believe it would be at 58.63% of capacity.

I want to understand how this will perform for different aggregation queries running on it. I want to create a set of staged pipeline aggregations which write to a different collection which are used as source data for business insights analysis.

Across 8.4 billion transactional documents, I aim to create this aggregated data in a different collection by a set of individual services which output using `$out` to avoid any issues with the 16Mb document size for a single results set.

Am I being overly ambitious here expection MongoDb to be able to:

1. Store that much data in a collection
2. Aggregate and output the results of refreshed data to drive business insights in a separate collection for consumption by services which provide discrete aspects of a customer's business

Any feedback welcome, I want to understand where the limit is of using MongoDb as opposed to other technologies for quantity data storage and use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on how big collection in MongoDB can be (in a replica set or a sharded cluster). I think you are confusing this with maximum collection size after reaching which it cannot be sharded.

[MongoDB Docs: Sharding Operational Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#sharding-operational-restrictions)

For the amount of data you are planning to have it would make sense to go with a sharded cluster from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @Kiril, with the amount of volume of documents which I plan on using in an aggregation, do you think MongoDb will handle it ok? I understand that storage size is only one aspect I need to consider. Thanks, Matt

Comment: Your aggregation query performance will depend on how much data is returned for a particular query and what indexes can be used to support that query. If for your reports you need to comb through 18TB of data for queries to be fast data has to be in memory or on fast SSDs.